# CMDで変数名に変数を入れた場合の表示方法

Tags: batch-file

例えば以下のようなモノを作成します。

```
@ECHO OFF
SET A=HOGE1
SET /A %A%EGOH+=1
ECHO %HOGE1EGOH%
PAUSE
```

ECHO には 1 と正しく表示されます。
しかしこれは『%A%』が『HOGE1』であるが為に動作しています。
そこで

```
ECHO %A%EGOH
PAUSE
```

例えばこの様な書き方で 1 を表示させたいのですが、このままでは動作しません。
どのように記述すれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setlocal)を使うと遅延評価が使えます。遅延評価は`!変数名!`と記述します。つまり`!%A%EGOH!`と記述すると`%A%`が展開されて`!HOGE1EGOH!`となり、遅延評価により`1`が表示されます。

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET A=HOGE1
SET /A %A%EGOH+=1
ECHO !%A%EGOH!
PAUSE
```

Comment: For文にしか使った事がなかったので盲点でした。
おかげで無事に目的に近づくことが出来ました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

参考までに`setlocal`を使わない場合こんな方法があります。

```
@ECHO OFF
SET A=HOGE1
SET /A %A%EGOH+=1
CALL ECHO %%%A%EGOH%%
PAUSE
```

Comment: 今回は使用することはありませんでしたが、今後何かの拍子に使うときが来るかもしれないので大変参考になます。ありがとうございます。